# Show Screenshot of Google Map in a jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery

I'm showing a route in the google map inside my webpage. My map is been showed inside a div as follows

```
<div id="map_canvas" ></div>
```

It will be getting updated time to time. How can i get a screen shot of the map and show it in a jQuery dialog box as an image?

It'll be a great help if anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: Did you try any library like [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) ?

Comment: nope.. i have already used javascript to show the map and the route. I already have the jquery popup.. I just need to show a screenshot of the map, and show it in the popup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to take a screenshot of google maps yourself and show it on your page. You'll have to use the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)  so you don't get into trouble.

But apart from that it should be no problem to show it inside a [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples), as Asif pointed out or a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) if you prefer.

Comment: thanks...i will have to redraw the route by sending parameters right? wont it become slow??

Comment: @era yes, google requires that you get every maps data from their servers and not host it yourself. but it should not be a problem, their servers and connection are pretty fast :)

Comment: i added a google map like mention in question and i allow user to make a click and add marker i need to take snapshot when submit button is pressed

Comment: @lawrenceoverflow Please post your problem as a new question, as I'm sure more people will be able to help you that way!